# How to share spring MVC project from 'Spring Tool Suite' executable without code?

Tags: spring, maven, share, project, executable

I have created a maven based spring project and successfully completed it and now this project can run on browser with localhost:8080 server i want to share my project with other and i don't want to make the code is visible or he get only executable form of project so how does it possible ?

I can share my database to that person (mysql)
And spring project with executable form (without code part)

I have created this project as 
Maven Project 
and then added some dependencies 
here is my pom.xml file

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.p1</groupId>
<artifactId>proejct1</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>Project Share</name>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring.version>5.0.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <!--spring.version>4.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version -->
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Servlet API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.0.M6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- dependency> <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId> <artifactId>tomcat-jsp-api</artifactId> 
        <version>9.0.0.M13</version> </dependency -->

    <!-- Spring Core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring MVC -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JSTL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Security -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sitemesh</groupId>
        <artifactId>sitemesh</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
        <!--version>4.3.6.Final</version -->
    </dependency>
    <!-- MySQL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.46</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <!--version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <!--version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version -->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
        <!--version>2.5.0</version -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
        <!--version>2.5.0</version -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <!--version>2.0.1.Final</version -->
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <!--version>5.2.4.Final</version -->
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext-pdfa</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext-xtra</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.itextpdf.tool</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlworker</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>pms</finalName>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Create the executaion jar and share the same.

Comment: so you basically want to convert a .war file into a .exe file? correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Not exactly i just want to give my project to other member who can implement that same one for practice but without code so it would be better to make executable jar rather than exe as its java based project

Answer (score 0):

When you compile the spring-boot project it will create a jar in build folder(if that is not the case then need to tweak config to create a jar file).

You can share that jar, other person can execute that jar using simple java command.

```
java -jar spring-project-name.jar
```

Comment: thanks for that i have done some research with it and found to be make a jar file over it using assemble:plugin but now problem is my project is not spring boot and i have create it in WAR and  there is no main method as WebInitialiizer is there in which @Override --> onstartup()

Comment: this doc should help. 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging